# How do I discover the user's Desktop folder?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a little application in visual studio which loads a ROM in an emulator. 
I have two emulators and 20 ROMs.

I made a form and added a few buttons. When you click the Button it opens a new form and closes the old one. Then on the new form I have four buttons: each one loads a different ROM in an emulator. So when you press Button1 this code is triggered:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles yellow.Click
Shell("C:\Users\shifty\Desktop\pokemon games\Emulator\VBA\VisualBoyAdvance.exe ""C:\Users\shifty\Desktop\pokemon games\Roms\Yellow\Pokemon Yellow.gb""", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

It works fine - I click it and it loads the game in the emulator. The bit im having trouble with is the file paths. If I send this application to a friend, it would still look for "C:\Users\shifty\Desktop\" - but that's on my computer, not his.

Is there a way to make the application look for the file on his computer (without changing the file path to (C:\Users\""his user name""\Desktop))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076811/saving-to-a-folder-in-the-users-my-documents

Answer (score 41):

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`

This will resolve to be the desktop folder for the current user.

It will even work between XP, vista and Windows 7 properly.

Comment: @Spence 
could you put the code  where it needs to go then paste it back to me

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles yellow.Click
Shell("C:\Users\shifty\Desktop\pokemon games\Emulator\VBA\VisualBoyAdvance.exe ""C:\Users\shifty\Desktop\pokemon games\Roms\Yellow\Pokemon Yellow.gb""", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub

Comment: @Mc SH1FTY: Come *ON!* @Pwninsteing and @Spence both gave you the right answer. Do they have to spoonfeed it to you as well? Hint to figure it out yourself: `Print Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop))`. See what the result of that matches in your code.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett 
like i said in the question which someone deleted loads from BTW
im not that good at coding im still learning and every time i type that code which everyone is going on about i get about 10 errors saying stuff like syntax errors, invalid codes, unexpected end to string  and loads more iv tried loads of diffreent sites and they all think they know what to do but they only give me the code which alone is useless i need help  not jibberish

Comment: @Mc SH1FTY: If you look down upon the excellent, valid answers you are getting for free from experts here as "jibberish", then clearly you are at the wrong site, and you may want to go try the other, better ones you seem to know. There are plenty of other beginners here, and people here will gladly help them and do so all the time. Luckily, only a small minority of beginners whine for spoonfeeding -- and very few people will spoonfeed when whined at.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett  im not whining at anyone  im just asking for a bit of help  i dont know where that code  go's or how to use it  iv tried  but i keep getting errors  and yes i am a beginner i started my application yesterday  i started coding yesterday  and all i ask for is a bit of help and all i get is

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop))

it might be the right answer but i dont know what to do with that 
is it too much to ask for  for a bit of help without getting bitched at by you ???

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett  and im doing this for other people my application works fine for me
all i need is a bit of help getting it to work for other people its not like im trolling for my personal gain im trying to do this for the members of a gaming site   i found an application similar but didnt have many games on it  i made my own with 20 games so far and if people what to suggest games they can then ill add them i already have loads waiting for my app  but if i give them it now it wont work i just want help making it work for everyone

Comment: To do this with PowerShell, use the following: `[Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)`

Answer (score 9):

Old post but I have to side with Mc Shifty.  You can't assume that everyone is a coding expert.  If they were then they wouldn't be here asking questions like that.

None of the answers given above were complete

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop))`   <<< includes and extra )
`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));`  <<< extra ) and the ; is C or java not VB which he is obviously using by his example code.

Both of those only give you half of the required code to generate something usable.

```
Dim s As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

The above code will give you the result needed, **c:\users\shifty\desktop**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles yellow.Click
    Dim s As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Shell(s & "\Desktop\pokemon games\Emulator\VBA\VisualBoyAdvance.exe " & s & "\pokemon games\Roms\Yellow\Pokemon Yellow.gb""", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: The other answers don't assume he is an expert, they just assume he should know how to google a method and read about it on MSDN (a basic skill every programmer should have)

Comment: @Wayne So, you find 40 muddled comments more succinct than two sentences of clarity? It's people like you that make SO suck ;)

Comment: @Mattt I find the very succinct, top voted, answer to be more than clear enough for any user who wants to learn.

Comment: My point is still valid. You and others waste a lot of time chastising people instead of just answering. In some situations, that is acceptable... most of the time, you're just being jerks. To each their own I guess.

Comment: The response is incorrect anyway, is it not?  This will produce **c:\users\shifty\desktop\Desktop\pokemon games\Emulator\VBA\VisualBoyAdvance.exe**.  Note the "desktop\Desktop"

Answer (score 4):

There's a mechanism to get the current user's Desktop directory, using [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx).

Usage:

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));`

Comment: so where would i put the code
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop))
in to the one i already have ????

Answer (score 3):

I had problems using the `Environment.GetFolderPath` method from previous answers.

The following works in VB 2012, `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop`

So, if you have a file on a users desktop named "contacts.txt", the following will display the full path,

```
' Desktop path
Dim desktopPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop

' Concatenate desktop path and file name
filePath = desktopPath & "/contacts.txt"

MsgBox(filePath)
```

---

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.specialdirectories.desktop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Really old post at this point, but hey, found what I was looking for.

MC SH1FTY, I assume you have figured this out already, but to do what you are trying to do:

1) Call in that code that Spence wrote as a variable (I'd declare it Globally, but that's my preference. To do that:

```
Public userDesktopLoc As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

2) Either use this DIRECTLY in your code, or make another string to concatenate a directory:

Option A)

```
Public emulatorPath As String = userDesktopLoc & "pokemon games\Emulator\VBA\VisualBoyAdvance.exe "
Public romPath As String = userDesktopLoc & "pokemon games\Roms\Yellow\Pokemon Yellow.gb"
```

Then, within your Subroutine, replace your current `Shell` statement with:

```
Shell(emulatorPath & romPath, vbNormalFocus)
```

Or, Option B, which is thedsz's answer:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles yellow.Click
        Dim s As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        Shell(s & "\Desktop\pokemon games\Emulator\VBA\VisualBoyAdvance.exe " & s & "\pokemon games\Roms\Yellow\Pokemon Yellow.gb""", vbNormalFocus) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By using that you guarantee that the emulator is on the users desktop. This is not always the case. I know I move things around that I download or a friend sends to me. It's better to use App.Path and make sure your emulator.exe is in the directory with your little front end program (usually the case).

Answer (score 0):

the answer is simple.

- put this at the top of the form
- "Public thepath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)"
- that ensures that the file is on their desktop!
- then" click on your button or whatever you used to open the emu and type
- "Process.Start(thepath + "the emulator.exe "+ "the rom you want")

Answer (score -2):

You need to use a file open dialog to choose your path for the two files.  [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/GUI/FileOpendialogfilefilter.htm) is an example.

You then use the two paths in your code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles yellow.Click
    Shell(emulatorPath + "\"" + romPath + "\"", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: all of that makes no sense to me whatsoever sorry