# Saving to a folder in the users "My documents"

Tags: .net, vb.net

When I create the installer for my application I am going to be creating a folder in their "My Documents", this folder is going to be used to save files from my application into.

I would like to have my application automatically pull up this directory when the save file &  open file dialogs open. Now my question is, what is the string I need to use to get to a folder in their "My documents"?

I know to get their my documents directory it goes something like this:

```
Dim dir as String  
dir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

But how about a folder in their my documents? Such as My Documents/Coolest Application Ever Files. This project is in VB.net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fine question, but please don't do this... at least not until you have something to save there.  The whole point of that folder in the first place was so that users had an easy way to get to their stuff, and everybody and their brother has filled it up with folders like the one you are about to create.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at `Path.Combine`.

```
dir = Path.Combine(dir, "Coolest Application Ever Files")
```

Just ensure it exists before your try to write to a file there.

```
If Not Directory.Exists(dir) Then
  Directory.Create(dir)
End If
```

Comment: Had to change Directory.Create(dir) to Directory.CreateDirectory(dir). Other than that it works great thanks alot, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

```vb
Dim filepath As String
filepath= IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "test.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are creating the folder in the "My Documents" folder, can you just assume that you already know the name of said folder?  So wouldn't:

```
dir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments & "\Your_Folder_Title\")
```

work?

Comment: Actually not, you have to insert a \ in between. And, that `EnvironmentPath` is wrong, too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just append the folder you're looking for to the MyDocuments special folder

```
dir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments & "/Coolest Application Ever Files")
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the folder to your documents with this line.

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "YourAppFolder")
```