# VB.NET | Get current user profile folder

Tags: vb.net

How can I use `'path'` to go to the user's current profile?

For example, I have this code:

```
        Dim fso, fldr
    fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")

    fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\Documents and Settings\%UserProfile%\Local Settings\TEST")

    'delete subfolders
    For Each subf In fldr.SubFolders

        subf.Delete(True)

    Next

    'delete subfiles
    For Each fsofile In fldr.Files

        fsofile.Delete(True)

    Next
```

I've tried this way and the path is unknown.

How can I make `C:\Documents and Settings\???\Local Settings\TEST`
to go to the current user's folder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076811/saving-to-a-folder-in-the-users-my-documents

Answer (score 16):

Use the 'userprofile' environment variable...

```
MsgBox(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile))
```

Comment: You should still carry on! How do you expect to get help if your not giving information...

Answer (score 2):

On my Windows 8.1, I cannot access Local Settings folder. It's right protected. As far as getting the right folder path is concerned, I think the answer is already posted above. Just append your custom folder path to the `UserProfile` Folder path returned by `Environment` of DotNet.

Something like:

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) & "\Local Settings\TEST"`

Answer (score 0):

Get the Local AppData folder:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

And then concatenate it with your "TEST" folder using `Path.Combine` method.
See [SpecialFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) msdn pages.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, using VB6.0 Sp6

```
    Dim myDocuPath As String
    myDocuPath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents"
```

Comment: Why does this work? Also, can you format your code in the editor so it looks like code?

Comment: Sorry about that format thing, i corrected it with 4 spaces before that code,  try again