# Send contents of text box to notepad document VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, textbox, notepad

I am creating a program that when my runners enter their time into a text box it will immediately export it to a file on their desktop(pre created) called times.txt. Each time they enter a time I want the time they entered to be added on a new line in the notepad file.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Public Class Form2
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  End Sub
End Class
```

Can anyone give me the code I need for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look into the `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IO.File.AppendAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
 Dim desktopPath As String =
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
 Dim fileName As String = "times.txt"
 Dim fullPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(desktopPath, fileName)
 IO.File.AppendAllLines(fullPath, {"Some new line in the file"})
```

Other ways to get user desktop folder path:

- [How do I discover the user's Desktop folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463280/how-do-i-discover-the-users-desktop-folder)

Comment: How can I make {"Some new line in the file"} change to what the content entered in the tex box is? @Neolisk

Comment: @user3448601: replace with `{textbox1.Text}`