# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in code

Tags: vb.net, excel

i keep getting An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred errors with this code. Its pointing to  "Dim TheRange As Range = oSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value"
i did break and found that the value for TheRange was nothing..not sure what i did wrong or its something in plain sight that i am not seeing it.

```
 Dim OExcel As New Excel.Application
    OExcel.Visible = False 'Put true if you want to see the excel application showing on the screen
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook = OExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\cpushpa\Desktop\test.xlsx")
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet = TryCast(oBook.Worksheets(1), Worksheet)
    Dim TheRange As Range = oSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value
    Dim Data As String = ""
    For TheColumn As Integer = 1 To TheRange.Columns.Count
        For TheRow As Integer = 1 To TheRange.Rows.Count
            Data &= CType(oSheet.Cells(TheRow, TheColumn), Range).Value.ToString & ","
        Next
        Data = Data.TrimEnd(","c) & vbCrLf
    Next
    oBook.Close()
    OExcel.Quit()
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(OExcel)
    Using FileWriter As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText("C:\Users\cpushpa\Desktop\DataTextFile.txt")
        FileWriter.WriteLine(Data)
    End Using
    Process.Start("Notepad", "C:\Users\cpushpa\Desktop\DataTextFile.txt")
```

Comment: study the answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/q/1464281/1070452

Comment: hi Plutonix, thanks for the quick response, the link you provided guides on how to read a cell from excel but not copy the cell if im not wrong.

Comment: how can you copy (get) the cell contents without reading it?

Comment: yes i understand,what im asking here is after you read it how do you copy it, into notepad.I`ve adjusted my code with the code from the link to open the excel document file and read the cell content but how do you copy the data that has been read into a notepad.

Comment: if putting it on the clipboard for the user is not enough, you could  write the text to a file then open that file with notepad as described [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22572278/1070452)

Comment: alright will try that way plutonix,i already have an excel file with data and an empty notepad on the desktop, just need to transfer certain cell contents into the empty notepad on the desktop. thanks